# Node: fs.readdir() always returns files

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have this code snippet:

```
fs.readdir(STLFilesDir, (err, files) => {
            if (err)
            {
                console.log(err);
                throw err;
            }
            if (files)
            {
                console.log(files); //files is an array with all the files in the directory
                res.render('prerenderer.ejs');
            }   
            else 
            {
                console.log('no files found');
                res.render('prerenderer.ejs');
            }
```

However, in the case of not having any files in the folder, I dont't get what is expected.
Instead of seeing no files found, in the console.
I get this `[]`.
This is an empty object.
This means that the last `else` does not work. So `fs.readdir()` always returns an array - even if it's empty.
So how can I get the `else` portion to run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript, an empty array `[]` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), so you'll want `if (files.length)` instead of `if (files)`